# When I right click on intellij, I do not get the run button for a JS File

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-u-j7uqU7sI&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_

I was following the instructions from the video from the above link  until 8:43

After writing  "  console.log('something');   " in intelliJ(its a JS File), When I right click, I do not get the run button. [image]

Answer (score 0):

you may be need to edit run configuration.

[image]

[image]

then you can just click run to see the result

Comment: My edit configuration window is empty.I can see "My apps" is your image, but mine is empty.Gosh ..how do I post an image of that?

Comment: [jetbrain website](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/running-and-debugging-node-js.html)